# RStudio - Script opened with wrong encoding, how to get back original characters?

Tags: character-encoding, rstudio

I have a file in Spanish, when seen on my teacher's PC a bit of text would display as

```
regresión cuantílica más
```

but now that I've opened on mine I see this:

```
regresiÃÂ³n cuantÃÂ­lica mÃÂ¡s
```

I have tried "Save with Encoding" to ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 but it doesn't seem to change anything. Will I need to run some regex replacements on my file or is there a simpler way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already saved it and you've lost the original version of the file, it will be a pain to recover.

What you should have done when you noticed the bad characters was "Reopen with encoding", and chosen the "UTF-8" encoding.  If you can still get the original file, do this now.

If you can't, then you're stuck with lots of manual fixing.  Accented characters (and Euro signs, and a few other things) will show up as multi-character sequences.  When you recognize one, use search and replace to replace that sequence with the correct character.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that my teacher uploaded the file with its incorrect encoding (or perhaps the school server altered it somehow?). Find and replace it is.

Comment: There isn't an "incorrect encoding" here, there's just a different encoding than RStudio was assuming.  If you tell it the correct encoding, it will work.